# Fetch details in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inserted values product-price, name and size in wordpress. The insert code is below

```
function products_save_postdata($post_id) {
  if (isset ($_POST['price'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', esc_attr($_POST['price']));
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['product_name'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'product_name', esc_attr($_POST['product_name']));
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['size'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'size', esc_attr($_POST['size']));
  }
}
```

How can i fetch this inserted data?

Comment: Do you want extract product attributes out of function ?

Comment: Yes. I want the product details i have inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function instead of yours:

```
function products_save_postdata($post_id)
{
  $array = array();

  if (isset ($_POST['price'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', esc_attr($_POST['price']));
    $array['price'] = $_POST['price'];
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['product_name'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'product_name', esc_attr($_POST['product_name']));
    $array['product_name'] = $_POST['product_name'];
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['size'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'size', esc_attr($_POST['size']));
    $array['size'] = $_POST['size'];
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Get values with:

```
$post_data = products_save_postdata($post_id);

echo $post_data['price'];
echo $post_data['product_name'];
echo $post_data['size'];
```

Comment: I have inserted it correctly. I just need to fetch it to display in my front end. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yaa i got this but I want to display it in another page. Where i will get the value of $post_id.Thanks

Comment: Hmm. I thought that you'll get attributes after post. So do yo want use `$_SESSION`?

Comment: No i want to display it. I want to create a list to show saved data.

Comment: You can achive with `SESSION` or should run a new query that getting last product.

Comment: You are not understanding my problem. This will be my admin part where admin can add products. I have done this part. I want to show the details which admin had inserted in user part means in front end. How will i do it. Please help me.

Comment: I understood. I think you can do this with `mysql query`. Just run `SELECT` query like: `SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 10;`. Sorry, I can not be more helpful.

Comment: you can use 
"get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );"
here is detail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: where i will get $post_id.